# c# change to next page on quiz

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2010

Hello im having trouble with changing to next question on my quiz.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Random random = new Random();
        int Month = random.Next(0);


        if (Month == 0)
        {
            radioButton1.Text = "January";
            radioButton2.Text = "April";
            radioButton3.Text = "August";
            SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\Callum\Documents\My Projects (Dissertation)\App sounds and pictures\Unit 8 Months (Complete)\Audio\1. Enero – January.Wav");
            simpleSound.Play();
        }

        if (Month == 1)
        {
            radioButton1.Text = "July";
            radioButton2.Text = "December";
            radioButton3.Text = "February";
            SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\Callum\Documents\My Projects (Dissertation)\App sounds and pictures\Unit 8 Months (Complete)\Audio\2. Febero – February.Wav");
            simpleSound.Play();
        }
        if (Month == 2)
        {
            radioButton1.Text = "May";
            radioButton2.Text = "September";
            radioButton3.Text = "March";
            SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\Callum\Documents\My Projects (Dissertation)\App sounds and pictures\Unit 8 Months (Complete)\Audio\3. Marzo – March.Wav");
            simpleSound.Play();
        }
        if (Month == 3)
        {
            radioButton1.Text = "April";
            radioButton2.Text = "August";
            radioButton3.Text = "March";
            SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\Callum\Documents\My Projects (Dissertation)\App sounds and pictures\Unit 8 Months (Complete)\Audio\4. Abril – April.Wav");
            simpleSound.Play();
        }
        if (Month == 4)
        {
            radioButton1.Text = "March";
            radioButton2.Text = "May";
            radioButton3.Text = "November";
            SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\Callum\Documents\My Projects (Dissertation)\App sounds and pictures\Unit 8 Months (Complete)\Audio\5. Mayo – May.Wav");
            simpleSound.Play();
        }
        if (Month == 5)
        {
            radioButton1.Text = "July";
            radioButton2.Text = "June";
            radioButton3.Text = "February";
            SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\Callum\Documents\My Projects (Dissertation)\App sounds and pictures\Unit 8 Months (Complete)\Audio\6. Junio – June.Wav");
            simpleSound.Play();
        }
static int i = 0;


 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int Month = random.Next(0);

        if (Month == 0)

        if (radioButton1.Checked)
        {
            label1.Text = "Correct";
            radioButton2.Enabled = false;
            radioButton3.Enabled = false;
        }
        else if (radioButton2.Checked)
        {
            label1.Text = "Incorrect";
            radioButton1.Enabled = false;
            radioButton3.Enabled = false;
        }
        else if (radioButton3.Checked)
        {
            label1.Text = "Incorrect";
            radioButton1.Enabled = false;
            radioButton3.Enabled = false;
        }


        if (Month == 1)

            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                label1.Text = "Incorrect";
                radioButton2.Enabled = false;
                radioButton3.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                label1.Text = "Incorrect";
                radioButton1.Enabled = false;
                radioButton3.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (radioButton3.Checked)
            {
                label1.Text = "Correct";
                radioButton1.Enabled = false;
                radioButton3.Enabled = false;
            }


        if (Month == 2)

            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                label1.Text = "Incorrect";
                radioButton2.Enabled = false;
                radioButton3.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                label1.Text = "Incorrect";
                radioButton1.Enabled = false;
                radioButton3.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (radioButton3.Checked)
            {
                label1.Text = "Correct";
                radioButton1.Enabled = false;
                radioButton3.Enabled = false;
            }


        if (Month == 3)

            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                label1.Text = "Correct";
                radioButton2.Enabled = false;
                radioButton3.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                label1.Text = "Incorrect";
                radioButton1.Enabled = false;
                radioButton3.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (radioButton3.Checked)
            {
                label1.Text = "Incorrect";
                radioButton1.Enabled = false;
                radioButton3.Enabled = false;
            }


        if (Month == 4)

            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                label1.Text = "Incorrect";
                radioButton2.Enabled = false;
                radioButton3.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                label1.Text = "Correct";
                radioButton1.Enabled = false;
                radioButton3.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (radioButton3.Checked)
            {
                label1.Text = "Incorrect";
                radioButton1.Enabled = false;
                radioButton3.Enabled = false;
            }


        if (Month == 5)

            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                label1.Text = "Incorrect";
                radioButton2.Enabled = false;
                radioButton3.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                label1.Text = "Correct";
                radioButton1.Enabled = false;
                radioButton3.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (radioButton3.Checked)
            {
                label1.Text = "Incorrect";
                radioButton1.Enabled = false;
                radioButton3.Enabled = false;
            }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        radioButton1.text = Month[i];
        radioButton2.text = Month[i];
        radioButton3.text= Month[i];

        i = (i + 1) % 5;

    }
```

3 errors come up saying "'System.Windows.Form.RadioButton' does not contain a definition for 'text' and no extension method 'text' accepting a first arguement type ' System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly refference)

Im new to this and trying to teach myself c# so please be patient with me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you simplify your question, seems it too long

Answer (score 2):

C# is case-sensitive. The property you are looking for is Text, not text.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    radioButton1.Text = Month[i];
    radioButton2.Text = Month[i];
    radioButton3.Text= Month[i];

    i = (i + 1) % 5;

}
```

Comment: Cheers that did help but its still not changing page it comes up with an error when I click the button saying "NullReferenceException was unhandled" "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Any ideas??

Comment: @callum - That's because the variable `Month` is out of scope.  It was defined in a different method.  Define it as a field of the class, not the method.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Rodrigo's answer:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    radioButton1.Text = Month[i];
    radioButton2.Text = Month[i];
    radioButton3.Text= Month[i];

    i = (i + 1) % 5;

}
```

Here you are trying to set the `Text` property (string) to and integer (Month).

Try:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    radioButton1.Text = Month[i].ToString();
    radioButton2.Text = Month[i].ToString();
    radioButton3.Text= Month[i].ToString();

    i = (i + 1) % 5;

}
```

Also, each of those RadioButtons will have the same text (Month number). Not sure if that is intended.

Additionally, you should use `if else` or a `switch` statement instead of `if` blocks in this case when checking for the current month. Currently, if `Month == 1`, it will still be checked against 2, 3, 4, etc needlessly.

Finally, consider limiting the creation of random numbers to a [specified range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx).